# C#: SMTP login with special characters in password

Tags: c#, passwords, smtp, special-characters

I try to send an email via SMTP. Within my SMTP account I use some special characters: "äöü".

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(this.Host, this.Port);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.Login, this.Password);
// setting message
client.Send(message);
```

I always get the server's error message "Authentication required".

When I change the password to another one without special characters, everything works fine.

How can I pass special characters to the SMTP server? And is this working for several servers like GMX, WEB, T-ONLINE, Googlemail, ...?

By the way: I need to work with .Net 2.0!

Thanks for any hints,
Mate

Comment: When you debug line 2 and inspect `this.Password`, are the characters correct?  I'm wondering if it's encoding it.

Comment: Yes, they are perfectly right: "123äöü"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the authentication mechanism used, the charset used to encode the string may be wrong for the particular server you are authenticating against.

Some servers use a non UTF-8 charset for PLAIN and LOGIN SASL mechanisms (i.e. they are setup to use the region's locale charset). Unfortunately, there's no way for a client to know what charset that is.

Other SASL mechanisms like DIGEST-MD5 allow the client & server to negotiate which charset is used (and usually ends up being UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks for this information. But how can I tell SmtpClient what charset it has to use, or how can I adjust the password so that it is passed correctly for a successful authentication?

Comment: You could try using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and see if that works for you (although it requires .NET 4.0). It doesn't allow specifying the charset, either, but it can provide a lot more diagnostic info (using a ProtocolLogger) and it also supports DIGEST-MD5 and other authentication mechanisms.